# How to join different pandas dataframes stored on a list of dictionar ordered by multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data in a list. Each item of the list is a dictionary with a unique key and the value of the dictionary is a DataFrame that contains 6 columns + index col.

```
    list = [{"A": Participation    Assignment     Words   Creativeness   Innovative Great
     Date                                                        
     2021-01-02  95.00  75.00  75.00  79.00     100      OK
     2021-01-05  83.00  83.00  83.00  80.00     100      OK
     2021-01-06  98.88  78.88  77.00  77.00     34       OK
     2021-01-07  77.00  77.00  77.00  77.00     150      OK
     2021-01-08  79.00  79.00  70.00  70.00     99       OK
     ...            ...     ...     ...     ...      ...      ...
     2021-02-18  65.67  36.67  35.59  36.88     94       OK
     2021-02-19  60.94  38.00  36.94  38.72     75       OK
     2021-02-22  40.00  43.80  40.80  42.71     82       OK
     2021-02-23  42.00  43.81  38.99  42.29     174      OK
     2021-02-24  42.00  45.00  42.00  44.17     175      OK
     
     [1065 rows x 6 columns]}, "B": Participation    Assignment     Words   Creativeness   Innovative Great
     Date                                                        
     2021-01-02  95.00  75.00  75.00  79.00     100      OK
     2021-01-05  83.00  83.00  83.00  80.00     100      OK
     2021-01-06  98.88  78.88  77.00  77.00     340      OK
     2021-01-07  77.00  77.00  77.00  77.00     150      OK
     2021-01-08  79.00  79.00  70.00  70.00     93       OK
     ...            ...     ...     ...     ...      ...      ...
     2021-02-18  65.67  36.67  35.59  36.88     94       OK
     2021-02-19  60.94  38.00  36.94  38.72     95       OK
     2021-02-22  40.00  43.80  40.80  42.71     182      OK
     2021-02-23  42.00  43.81  38.99  42.29     174      OK
     2021-02-24  42.00  45.00  42.00  44.17     75       OK
     
     [1065 rows x 6 columns]}, ...]
```

What I want to do is to have a large DataFrame where the general index is the Date, the first index Column is the respective key of each dictionary and the sub index of this is

```
      A                                                                               B
            Participation    Assignment     Words   Creativeness   Innovative Great   Participation    Assignment     Words   Creativeness   Innovative  Great
Date
2021-01-02  95.00            75.00          75.00   79.00          100        OK      95.00            75.00          75.00   79.00          100         OK
```

Something like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First dont use variable `list`, because python code word (`builtin`).

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), with dictionary is created `MultiIndex` from keys of dicts:

```
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
```